# How to download .app(dot app) file using Unity3D C#?

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I am trying to download a dot app(MacOS file) from my Unity3D C# code.

I have **hosted this file** on my server at path: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Testing/installer.app

In Mac, it shows me as a single file. But when i download it, **downloaded successfully, but with nothing downloaded**.

My code is working fine with other files, i.e., zip, txt, etc, but not with the dot app.

Using FileZilla, I saw that this file is showing as a folder.

I have **tried downloading this folder recursively & build into dot app file again**, but the dot app **does not work**. I think the file **lost its signature** or something.

Can anybody help me with downloading this dot app file OR any other way to download it?

***Code used to download:***

```
WWW www = new WWW(a_itemToDownload.URL);

while (!www.isDone)
{
    //Instance.Log("Progress: " + (float)www.progress);
    if (a_itemToDownload.OnDownloading != null)
        a_itemToDownload.OnDownloading.Invoke(a_itemToDownload.ItemId, l_fileName, www.progress);

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: "I have hosted this file on my server"... this is your problem.  It's a directory, not a file.  You need to package it in some way.

Answer (score 1):

`.app`s are actually directories in Mac OS X. You can right click the app file in Finder and choose "Show Package Contents". It will display contents of the application.

You should, perhaps, pack it in a .zip archive and unpack it on the client-side instead.

Comment: I had already tried doing the same. But when i unpack the zip, Archiver extract each file & folder recursively and hence losing dot app file.

Comment: Just a random idea, but if you can't zip it, can you rename it? Perhaps rename it from "file.app" to "file.bin" or something, then change it back once it's been downloaded

Comment: @SatbirSingh uhh.. but that "dot app file" isn't the file, it is a directory! It just looks like a file. You can rename the directory back to the "Installer.app", though it's strange that your zip archiver omits the ".app" at the end of folder name.